# Excel 2 sheets looking at date, AND the cell next to it, and give a color to a cell

Tags: excel, date

I need to implant an AND function, so when I look at some dates on "Year sheet" then I need to look at the cell next to it, and if that cell has the text "bit", then it colors the cell on sheet1

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(DATE(YEAR(Year!$B$2),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Year!$B$2),1,3))+AG5*7,Year!$B$6:$B$40,0),"")
```

AG5 = the weeknumber 31 and is an integer.

Can someone guide me, where to add the AND() function.

Year sheet

[image]

[image]

Comment: AND should be used with an IF statement. Could you please post some data example? would be conditional formatting an option for you?

Comment: AG5 gets the value according to cell B2 in sheet named `Aret`. In that cell, the date you have is 30-07-2018. So you want to check in that date has the text `bit` in the adyacent cell?

Answer (score 1):

As Foxfire And Burns And Burns explained in his comment. One solution would be a conditional formatting. 
The AND Function works with conditions and returns only TRUE or FALSE, which is what you use in conditional formatting.

Go to Conditional Formating => Create a new Rule => Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

In your example if the formula you posted only returns the row of a Cell and you want to check if the cell next to it has a "bit" inside you can type something in the form:

```
=AND(A1=yourdate,INDIRECT("C" & MATCH(DATE(YEAR(Year!$B$2),1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Year!$B$2),1,3))+AG5*7,Year!$B$6:$B$40,0),0)="bit")
```

And replace "A1=yourdate" by your first condition

**More Generally on the And and conditional formatting**

If I put as a new rule for the whole worksheet:

```
=AND(A1="";B1=6)
```

I obtain the following color every time my two conditions are filled

[image]

I hope it helped a bit.

Comment: Hi Pierre44
I can see what you are doing, if it's one date - but can't get it to work when I want to look at a group of dates like my image.

Comment: Can you type your formula for one date here?. How does your sheet1 look like?

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand.

Comment: The sheet1 is added with an image.
What formula for the date will you see ?